# ZX Spectrum+ with SCART Interface doesn't display anything

Tags: zx-spectrum, screen, scart

I have an **ZX Spectrum+** that came with a **SCART interface** (unknown brand, all I know is that it's french and that the blue logo seems to spell "IS").

It didn't came with its original power supply so I bought a **9 Volts** and **2.25 Amps** power supply.

When I plug the SCART and the power supply, nothing shows up on the screen.

I don't think the computer is broken as the internal regulator gets hot (quite a lot) when the power supply is plugged (I read that it is normal for it to get really hot), and I can hear a small noise on my headsphones when plugging the power supply, as if electricity was running normally.

I also didn't notice any leaking capacitors or any corrosion on both the ZX Spectrum+ mainboard and the SCART interface printed circuit board. The only thing I did before trying to boot it was to dust off the mainbaord and keyboard.

The problem being that there is no LED (none on this model) or speaker sound that tell me that computer is booting. So I don't know if the problem comes from the computer or only the peritel interface.

The screen I currently use is an Atari SC 1425. Maybe the SCART interface is no compatible with this screen?

What could prevent my ZX Spectrum+ from showing anything on-screen? Is it that either the peritel interface or the ZX Spectrum+ are broken?

Comment: Are you able to try another video output? I normally used the RF output on my ZX Spectrum.

Comment: You could also try to save something to the cassette port; this would put some sound on the speaker so that you can confirm the computer is actually running.

Comment: @Wilson Thanks for the idea, but how can I try to save to the cassette port without any video ouput? Is there a combination of keys and commands that I can input to do so?

Comment: Is it a grey or black Spectrum? Apparently these use two different cables. Here's one, with a link to the other: https://www.retrogamingcables.co.uk/sinclair-zx-spectrum-plus-128k-rgb-av-scart-cable-tv-lead-cord-for-sale

Comment: You could first type in a simple program. Something like `10 PRINT` `20 PRINT` `30 PRINT` would do just fine. (A hint: The ZX spectrum keyboard is weird and awkward; where you'd syntactically want a keyword, simply pressing P will enter the keyword `PRINT`.) Then, type `SAVE "a"` to save the program. SAVE is on the S key, so no need to type the rest of the word. To get the `"`, use SYMBOL SHIFT and P.

Comment: As you bought a replacement PSU, are you sure this is negative centre? The spectrum had PSUs that were the inverse polarity of basically everything else around.

Comment: @tofro I learned about the power connector polarity too late, I had already connected it with positive in the center. I did start another thread about this: http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1557/can-polarity-inversion-damage-a-zx-spectrum I have mixed answers on the question but there are chances I damaged the ZX Spcetrum+ by reversing polarity. Still, thank you for your comment.

Comment: For others testing ZX Spectrum functionality without video output: Press some key (like Enter) and the internal speaker (in the lower right corner of the computer) should emit a "click" sound.

Answer (score 3):

As has been noted in comments, you have probably damaged your ZX Spectrum+'s hardware by reversing the polarity of the power supply. In [mcleod_ideafix's answer](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1559/278) to the relevant question this is explained in more detail:

> You have damaged your Spectrum for sure. [...] [The 7805 regulator] is designed to survive overvoltage and short circuit conditions, but it is very vulnerable to a polarity inversion.